# Logarithmic averaging

Tags: vba, excel

I am developing a custom function that will calculate the logarithmic average of a range.  The answer for the post [logarithmic averaging question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23956551/logarithmic-averaging-preset-function-in-excel-using-ranges-as-input-values) is wrong but it is a starting point.  The problem lies in calculating the anti-logs (10^(0.1x)) of range values.  This is my first post so please forgive any missteps.

Here is my code:

```
Function logavg(rngValues As Range) As Double

    Dim lSumofValues As Double
    Dim lCountofValues As Double
    Dim lAntilog As Double
    Dim rngLoop As Range

    lSumofValues = 0
    lAntilog = 0
    lCountofValues = rngValues.Count 'Get count of values in items in range

'For loop - add the antilogs of the values in the range - does not work
    For Each rngLoop In rngValues
        lAntilog = WorksheetFunction.Power(10, 0.1 * rngLoop.Value)
        lSumofValues = lSumofValues + lAntilog
    Next

'Perform calculation - logarithmic average
    logavg = 10 * Log(lSumofValues / lCountofValues)

End Function
```

I tried this 'for' loop but it doesn't work:

```
    For Each rngLoop In rngValues
        lSumofValues = lSumofValues + (10 ^ (0.1 * rngLoop.Value))
    Next
```

This code for a simple (arithmetic) average works so I know that the range values are being transferred and used properly:

```
    For Each rngLoop In rngValues
    lSumofValues = lSumofValues + rngLoop.Value
    Next
    logavg = lSumofValues / lCountofValues
```

Test data is: 92.8, 79.1, 81.6, 78.3, 89.4, 86.5, 86.9

The arithmetic average is 84.9 and the logarithmic average is 87.6.

Two Excel formulae that calculate the logarithmic average of B2:B8 are:

a) array formula =10*LOG(SUM(10^(0.1*B2:B8))/COUNT(B2:B8)), and

b) standard formula =10*LOG(SUMPRODUCT(10^(0.1*B2:B8))/COUNT(B2:B8))

Thanks.

Comment: Do you just need the log base 10 average `logavg = 10 * WorksheetFunction.Log10(lSumofValues / lCountofValues)` rather than natural log?

Comment: Why don't you just use the worksheet formulae though?

Comment: Be aware that `LOG` from the formula is a log base 10 while the `Log` from VBA is a log base e. To get the log base 10 with VBA: `Log(x) / Log(10)`

Comment: @sjr Yes I need the log base 10 average, not the natural log.  The worksheet formulae are too inefficient when changing dozens of them at a time.

Comment: @FlorentB I didn't know that the VBA log is a natural log so thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a method using all VBA functions:

```
Function logAvg(myRng As Range) As Double
    Dim myCount As Long
    Dim D As Double
    Dim I As Long
    Dim V

    V = myRng
    For I = 1 To UBound(V, 1)
        D = D + 10 ^ (V(I, 1) * 0.1)
    Next I

    myCount = UBound(V, 1)
    D = D / myCount

    D = Log(D) / Log(10)
    logAvg = 10 * D

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

A tiny change:

```
Function logavg(rngValues As Range) As Double
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        Dim lSumofValues As Double
        Dim lCountofValues As Double
        Dim lAntilog As Double
        Dim rngLoop As Range

        lSumofValues = 0
        lAntilog = 0
        lCountofValues = rngValues.Count 'Get count of values in items in range

    'For loop - add the antilogs of the values in the range - does not work
        For Each rngLoop In rngValues
            lAntilog = .Power(10, 0.1 * rngLoop.Value)
            lSumofValues = lSumofValues + lAntilog
        Next

    'Perform calculation - logarithmic average
        logavg = 10 * .Log10(lSumofValues / lCountofValues)
    End With
End Function
```

[image]

Where my data is in **B1** through **B7**